# Clear template cache from the CLI?

Tags: craft3, cache, cli

I was looking for a way to clear the “template caches” and “compiled templates” from the CLI, as I want to automatically do this after every auto-deploy of the site I've created.

For this I was looking into the `craft` binary and its `cache/list` command. However, when running `./craft cache/list` it only returns me `cache (yii\caching\FileCache)`.

This felt kind of strange to me, as I was expecting a list similar to the one to be seen in the admin at the URL `/admin/utilities/clear-caches`:

[image: List of possible caches, as shown in the admin]

So hereby I'm wondering if it's possible to clear any of these caches show above from the CLI. Or is the `cache/clear` command for something else that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft-Scripts will do this for you: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts#clear_cachessh

You can see what it does via the source: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts/blob/master/scripts/clear_caches.sh

As for `cache/clear` this clear's Yii2's cache... which Craft CMS uses for almost nothing. Template Caches are always in the db, compiled templates are always cached on disk as files, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Will check out craft-scripts :)